# Diverging Implicit Error When Parsing JSON to Case Class in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit, play-json

I'm facing a strange error where I'm trying to parse a JSON String into a generic case class. My case class looks like this:

```
final case class LocationAPIObject[F[_]](
  countryCode: F[String],
  partyId: F[String],
  uid: F[String]
)
```

For a JSON that comes in like this:

```
  val js: JsValue = Json.parse("""{
    "countryCode": "us",
    "partyId": "123456"
  }""")
```

It results in a parse error:

```
diverging implicit expansion for type play.api.libs.json.Reads[T]
starting with method Tuple22R in trait GeneratedReads
```

Here is the sample code that I'm working on: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/aBQIUCTvTECNPgSjCjDFlw

Comment: Your class contains fields which are encapsulated effects. I don't think it should be possible to get an auto derived Codec for this.

Comment: If you are opened for using other JSON parsers then try jsoniter-scala. It is much handy in derivation and [supports parsing and serialization of higher-kinded types out of the box](https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter-scala/blob/02169c801d9e21ca426115a8e71134de262ab02e/jsoniter-scala-macros/shared/src/test/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/jsoniter_scala/macros/JsonCodecMakerSpec.scala#L2323-L2333). Also, it is [much more efficient in runtime](https://plokhotnyuk.github.io/jsoniter-scala/).

Comment: Check this updated [scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bhIj4nQYRqO3zTdwqUNtgw).

Comment: Thanks for the help. More or less what I wanted!

Comment: Note that Andriy Plokhotnyuk is promoting his own library, so this is not an unbiased recommendation.

Comment: @sarveshseri Encapsulated effect shouldn't be a problem. This type-class derivation works for example in Circe (see my answer) but doesn't for some reason in Play json. The issue is maybe in Play json derivation macros.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Yes, as long as we restrict the `F` to be such that `F[A]` is serializable for any serializable `A`. Or in other words, it must be possible to derive a `Decoder[F[A]]` given a `Decoder[A]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `diverging implicit expansion` error because you haven't specified type parameter. If you do

```
val locationAPI = Json.fromJson[LocationAPIObject[Option]](js)
```

then the error changes to `implicit not found: play.api.libs.json.Reads[LocationAPIObject[scala.Option]]. No Json deserializer found for type LocationAPIObject[Option]. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.`

The case class `LocationAPIObject` being parametrized with higher-kinded `F` ("fields which are encapsulated effects") shouldn't be a problem. The fields are of type `F[String]` so in order to derive instances of the type class `Reads` or `Format` for `LocationAPIObject[F]` it should be enough to know instances for `F[String]`.

But while this works for example in Circe

```scala
import io.circe.Decoder
import io.circe.parser.decode
import io.circe.generic.semiauto

implicit def locDec[F[_]](implicit ev: Decoder[F[String]]): Decoder[LocationAPIObject[F]] =
  semiauto.deriveDecoder[LocationAPIObject[F]]

decode[LocationAPIObject[Option]](
  """{
    "countryCode": "us",
    "partyId": "123456"
  }"""
)
// Right(LocationAPIObject(Some(us),Some(123456),None))
```

for some reason it doesn't in Play json:

```scala
implicit def locFormat[F[_]](implicit ev: Format[F[String]]): Format[LocationAPIObject[F]] =
  Json.format[LocationAPIObject[F]]
```

or

```scala
implicit def locFormat[F[_]](implicit ev: OFormat[F[String]]): OFormat[LocationAPIObject[F]] =
  Json.format[LocationAPIObject[F]]
// No instance of play.api.libs.json.Format is available for F, F, F in the implicit scope (Hint: if declared in the same file, make sure it's declared before)
```

or

```scala
implicit def locReads[F[_]](implicit ev: Reads[F[String]]): Reads[LocationAPIObject[F]] =
  Json.reads[LocationAPIObject[F]]
// No instance of play.api.libs.json.Reads is available for F, F, F in the implicit scope (Hint: if declared in the same file, make sure it's declared before)
```

So the thing seems to be in Play json derivation macros.

The easiest would be to define a codec manually as it was adviced in the comments.